# grid.hasChanges always returns true when I land on the page

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

`grid.hasChanges` always returns `true` when I land on the page.
That means that even though there have been no changes made to the `dataSource`, it still returns `true`.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Perhaps you could share some of your source code, if you didn't manage to resolve the problem. Better yet, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which will help us to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you haven't defined an Id field in your model schema. The [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/haschanges) has this to say:

> Requires an [`ID` field] to be configured in [schema.model.id](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model). Otherwise, will always return `true`

Hope this helps.